Naturality of the isomorphism in the proof of the characterization of pointwise Kan extensions
I'm having an issue with a proof relating pointwise Kan extensions. Let's introduce everything. A right (resp., left) Kan extension of $F:\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{E}$ along $K:\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{D}$ is said to be pointwise if it is preserved along the covariant (resp., contravariant) representable functor $\mathsf{E}(e,-)$ (resp., $\mathsf{E}(-,e)$), for all $e\in\mathsf{E}$. See [Riehl, 6.3.5] for a more detailed definition.
In [Riehl], we find:

Theorem 6.3.7. If $\mathsf{D}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are locally small, a right Kan extension of $F: \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{E}$ along $K: \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{D}$ is pointwise if and only if it can be computed by
$$
\operatorname{Ran}_K F(d) \cong \lim \left(d \downarrow K \xrightarrow{\Pi_d} \mathsf{C} \xrightarrow{F} \mathsf{E}\right),
$$
in which case, in particular, this limit exists. Dually, a left Kan extension of $F: \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{E}$ along $K: \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{D}$ is pointwise if and only if it can be computed by
$$
\operatorname{Lan}_K F(d) \cong \operatorname{colim}\left(K \downarrow d \xrightarrow{\Pi^d} \mathsf{C} \xrightarrow{F} \mathsf{E}\right),
$$
in which case, in particular, this colimit exists.

Riehl argues the implication $(\Leftarrow)$ right before stating Theorem 6.3.7: it's the fact that the functors $\mathsf{E}(e,-)$, $\mathsf{E}(-,e)$ commute respectively with all limits and colimits, plus [Riehl, Theorem 6.2.1]. She then proceeds to prove the other implication:

Proof [of Theorem 6.3.7.($\Rightarrow$)]. If $\operatorname{Ran}_K F$ is pointwise, then for any $e \in \mathsf{E}, \mathsf{E}\left(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F\right)$ is the right Kan extension of $\mathsf{E}(e, F-): \mathsf{C} \rightarrow$ Set along $K$. By the Yoneda lemma and the defining universal property of this right Kan extension
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\left(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F(d)\right)
\cong \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}}\left(\mathsf{D}(d,-), \mathsf{E}\left(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F\right)\right)
&\cong \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}(\mathsf{D}(d, K-), \mathsf{E}(e, F-)) \\
& \cong \operatorname{Cone}\left(e, F \Pi_d\right),
\end{align}
where the final natural isomorphism is the content of Lemma 6.3.8 below. This isomorphism exhibits $\operatorname{Ran}_K F(d)$ as the limit of $F \Pi_d: d \downarrow K \rightarrow \mathsf{E}$. $\square$

(Lemma 6.3.8 is just the assertion that $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}(\mathsf{D}(d, K-), \mathsf{E}(e, F-))
\cong \operatorname{Cone}\left(e, F \Pi_d\right)$; I don't include it here but readers can read it in [Riehl].) My concerns regarding the proof are:

Shouldn't we verify naturality of the iso
$$\tag{1}\label{iso}
\mathsf{E}\left(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F(d)\right) \cong \operatorname{Cone}\left(e, F \Pi_d\right)
$$
in $e$? It's what would make $\operatorname{Ran}_K F(d)$ represent the functor
$\operatorname{Cone}\left(-, F \Pi_d\right)$.

If issue 1 is reasonable, then how do we do prove naturality in $e$?



References
[Riehl] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context

Issue $1$ is always reasonable. Naturality is very important... and never checked. Even more so in the enriched setting

Notice you also need to worry about variation in $d$. The Kan extension is a functor!! morphisms matter

To prove the theorem, I am not sure whether naturality in $d$ is necessary. This other naturality was discusses here.

I elaborated in my answer
/long comment. You don’t need to prove naturality in $d$ but it is true and it is relevant in figuring out the other structure.

$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\D{\mathsf{D}}
\def\E{\mathsf{E}}
\def\ran{\operatorname{Ran}}
\def\lan{\operatorname{Lan}}
\def\A{\mathsf{A}}$Here is the proof of naturality of \eqref{iso} in $e$. Since the iso \eqref{iso} equals the composite
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F(d))
\overset{\label{a}(\mathrm{a})}{\cong} \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}}(\mathsf{D}(d,-), \mathsf{E}(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F))
&\overset{(\mathrm{b})}{\cong} \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}(\mathsf{D}(d, K-), \mathsf{E}(e, F-)) \\
&\overset{(\mathrm{c})}{\cong} \operatorname{Cone}\left(e, F \Pi_d\right),
\end{align}
naturality of \eqref{iso} follows from naturality of the isos $(\mathrm{a})$, $(\mathrm{b})$, $(\mathrm{c})$, which we shall show.
Nat. of $(\mathrm{a})$. This iso is given by the Yoneda lemma $G(d)\cong\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}}(\mathsf{D}(d,-),G)$, which is natural in $G$ [Riehl, Theorem 2.2.4].
Nat. of $(\mathrm{c})$. We have to check that given $g:e\to e'$, the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Cone}(e',F\Pi_d)
@>\cong>>
\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}(\mathsf{D}(d, K-), \mathsf{E}(e', F-))\\
@Vg^*VV@VV\mathsf{E}(g,F)_*V\\
\operatorname{Cone}(e,F\Pi_d)
@>\cong>>
\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}(\mathsf{D}(d, K-), \mathsf{E}(e, F-))
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. By direct inspection of the proof of [Riehl, Lemma 6.3.8], this follows easily.
Nat. of $(\mathrm{b})$. This isomorphism expresses the fact that $\operatorname{Ran}_KF$ is pointwise, i.e., $\mathsf{E}(e,\operatorname{Ran}_KF)=\operatorname{Ran}_K\mathsf{E}(e,F)$. Given general $F:\C\to\E$ and $K:\C\to\D$, the iso $(\mathrm{b})$ turns out to be a particular case of the isomorphism $\E^{\C}(G K, F) \cong \E^{\D}(G, \operatorname{Ran}_K F)$, which is natural in $F$ [Riehl, Proposition 6.1.5]. Thus, it suffices to show that if $g:e\to e'$ is a morphism in $\E$, then $\E(g,\ran_KF)=\ran_K\E(g,F)$. More generally:

Lemma. Suppose $F:\C\to\E$, $K:\C\to\D$, $L,L':\C\to\A$ are functors such that $\lan_KF$ exists, and that $L$ and $L'$ preserve $\lan_KF$ (i.e., $L\cdot\lan_KF=\lan_KLF$ and $L'\cdot\lan_KF=\lan_KL'F$). Then, for any $\delta:L\Rightarrow L'$, it holds
$$
\tag{2}\label{eq}
\delta\cdot\lan_KF=\lan_K\delta F.
$$

Proof. First we want to understand the action of the functor $\lan_K:\E^\C\to\E^\D$ on morphisms. It is implicitly defined in the proof of [Riehl, Proposition 6.1.5]. It uses the proof of [Riehl, Proposition 4.3.4], which instantiated in our situation says that from a natural transformation $\nu:F\Rightarrow F'$ of functors $\C\to\E$ we get a natural morphism
$$
\E^\D(\lan_KF',G)
\cong\E^\C(F',GK)
\xrightarrow{\nu^*}\E^\C(F,GK)
\cong\E^\C(\lan_KF,G)
$$
Going through this composite, an element $\alpha'\in \E^\D(\lan_KF',G)$ is mapped
$$
\alpha'
\mapsto\alpha'K\cdot\eta'
\mapsto\alpha'K\cdot\eta'\cdot\nu
\mapsto\begin{matrix}\text{the unique }\alpha:\lan_KF\Rightarrow G\\
\text{ s.t. }\alpha K\cdot\eta=\alpha'K\cdot\eta'\cdot\nu\end{matrix}
$$
where $\eta:F\Rightarrow\lan_KF\cdot K$ and $\eta':F'\Rightarrow\lan_KF'\cdot K$ are the universal comparison transformations. By the Yoneda lemma, if $\alpha'=1_{\lan_KF'}$, then $\lan_K\nu$ is the unique $\alpha:\lan_KF\Rightarrow\lan_KF'$ such that $\alpha K\cdot\eta=\eta'\cdot\nu$.

Thus, to verify \eqref{eq}, we must check $\delta_{\lan_KF\cdot K}\cdot L\eta=L'\eta\cdot\delta_F$ in the following diagram:

This equality is a particular case of the equality $\beta_{f'}\cdot {}_g\alpha={}_{g'}\alpha\cdot\beta_f$ that holds for a 2-cell diagram

in any 2-category: by middle four interchange $\beta_{f'}\cdot {}_g\alpha=\beta*\alpha={}_{g'}\alpha\cdot\beta_f$ (this is how one actually defines horizontal composition in the 2-category of 1-categories [003E]). $\square$

You're right that strictly speaking there is a little bit to check.
I would guess the point is that when you work with purely categorical constructions that are as nice as possible (as in this case), then everything is basically automatically as natural as possible, so such problems are usually never a problem in basic category theory (even though in $\infty$-category theory it's a different beast where naturality is not so easy to check anymore).
From your answer, it sounds like the naturality that was most difficult to check by hand was the naturality of
$$ \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}}\left(\mathsf{D}(d,-), \mathsf{E}\left(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F\right)\right)
\cong \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}(\mathsf{D}(d, K-), \mathsf{E}(e, F-)) $$
in $e$.
Here is a more immediate way to see this. It's an incarnation of the fact that adjunctions can be checked objectwise(!)
Definition. Let $R: \mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{C}$ be a functor and $c \in \mathsf{C}, d \in \mathsf{D}$ and a morphism $\eta : d \to Rc$ in $\mathsf{D}$. We say that $\eta$ witnesses $c$ as a left-adjoint object to $d$ under $R$ if the composite
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(d,-) \xrightarrow{R} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(Rd, R-) \xrightarrow{\eta^*} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(c,R-)$$
is an isomorphism of functors $\mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{Set}$.
Lemma. Let $R:\mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{C}$ be a functor and $\mathsf{C}_R \subseteq \mathsf C$ be the full subcategory spanned by those objects $c \in \mathsf{C}$ which admit a left-adjoint object. Then, these assemble into a functor $L:\mathsf{C}_R \to \mathsf{D}$ which induces an adjunction $$L : \mathsf{C}_R \rightleftarrows \operatorname{essim} L : R. $$
Proof. This is shown in K-Theory where it is phrased in the language of $\infty$-categories but you can read it as if it were in $1$-categories. In Emily's book this is essentially indicated in Remark 4.2.7.
In this new language given two functors $F:\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{E}, K : \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$ a right Kan extension $\operatorname{Ran}_K F : \mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{E}$ (together with the 2-morphism datum) is a right adjoint object to $F$ under $K^* : \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}} \to \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}$ essentially by definition.
So as we are considering pointwise Kan extensions, $\mathsf{E}(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F-)$ is a right adjoint object to $\mathsf{E}(e, F-)$ under $K^*$. So in particular, the isomorphism
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}}(K^*F, \mathsf{E}(e,F-)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}}}(F, \mathsf{E}(e, \operatorname{Ran}_K F-)) $$ is natural in $\mathsf{E}(e,F-)$ along those objects in $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{D}}$ which are right adjoint objects under $K^*$. These are in particular all $\mathsf{E}(e', F-)$ for $e' \in \mathsf{E}$. So now this isomorphism is natural in $\mathsf{E}(e,F-) \to \mathsf{E}(e', F-)$ which is the same as naturality in $e$ by the Yoneda Lemma.
Perhaps writing this much just for this setting was not that insightful, as in 1-category theory everything can reasonably be manually checked anyhow. Nonetheless, I want to remark that this is one of the only available and highly powerful techniques to actually construct functors in $\infty$-category theory, so it's worth knowing no matter what.

Thanks Qi! I think in your definition you mean "a morphism $\eta:c\to Rd$ in $\mathsf{C}$" and "witnesses $d$ as a left-adjoint object to $c$"? In the nLab, your definition is this one, and your lemma is this result.

Given a morphism $g:e'\to e$, how does it follow from what you've said that $\mathsf{E}(g,\operatorname{Ran}_KF)=\operatorname{Ran}_K\mathsf{E}(g,F)$? (This is what gives naturality of the iso.)

@ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Yeah, you‘re right, there are some typos, thanks! I‘ll fix them later. For your other question, I think this is essentially hidden in the last few lines, these functors that you indicate are naturally isomorphic, natural in those functors $\mathsf{E}(e, F-)$ and particularly in $e$. (Both are right adjoints and adjoints are unique.) But I don‘t think this isomorphism is needed in the way I set it up. Sorry, I think I‘m explaining poorly in this comment, I‘m not at my laptop right now.

Long comment.
You need to catch naturality in $e$ for sure; (1) of course, it's category theory... but (2) because it is only then that we get (as you say) universality of $\mathrm{Ran}_K(F)(d)$; only then could it be 'uniquely' picked out as the limit. However, if you're comfortable with simple pasting and whiskering, it's not too hard to see that naturality.
Secondly, watch out for naturality in $d$ as well. $\mathrm{Ran}_K(F)$ is uniquely described as a functor (and the data of a natural transformation) and all the isomorphisms present are necessarily natural in $d$, too. So we also figure out not only the limit description of the objects, but how it behaves on morphisms. If you are trying to check if a given functor is a pointwise Kan extension, then checking the objects are limits.. is not quite good enough. Moreover the data of all those isomorphisms actually uniquely specifies the limiting cone $(\mathrm{Ran}_K(F)(d)\to F\prod_d(c))_{c\in(d|K)}$, if you track carefully enough (these isomorphisms also specify the universal natural transformation between $\mathrm{Ran}_K(F)\circ K$ and $F$, if you look carefully enough). These aren't things you need to check per se to verify Riehl's claim in the $\implies$ direction to know $\mathrm{Ran}_KF(d)$ is abstractly that limit, but if you want to take a bunch of those limits and piece them together to the functor.. you will need to think about these things (so, it's relevant for the $\leftarrow$ direction).
I can offer a different proof using (co)ends if you wish.
